# python найти нужный цвет из спектра в фото

Tags: python

У меня есть фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На нем желтый цвет, фото обновляется (делаются новые скрины) и этот желтый цвет может быть разным: немного темнее, немного ярче и таких вариаций сотни, если не тысячи (разный rgb).

Как с помощью python определить, что это именно желтый цвет?

Comment: сначала определить для себя, какой диапазон является "именно желтым"

Comment: Прочесть фото любой библиотекой, которая может читать картинки, например, `Pillow`, и посмотреть `RGB` составляющие интересующих вас пикселов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевести цвет в HSL/HSV схему с помощью подходящей библиотеки, и убедиться, что оттенок (Hue) [лежит в диапазоне 51..60](http://www.workwithcolor.com/yellow-color-hue-range-01.htm) (могут быть и другие мнения о том, какие цвета жёлтые)

Comment: да неее, как минимум три цвета из того диапазона не попадают в "желтый" даже при весьма широком толковании

Comment: @Эникейщик Не буду возражать, я слегка дальтоник ;) На [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_yellow) вообще хз что к жёлтому относят